# AngularJS search for sibling property

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am working on AngularJS application. I want to know how to query sibling property of a variable. e.g. In my controller variable car exists.

```
rootApp.controller('Option2', function($scope){
        $scope.cars = [
            {model : "Ford Mustang", color : "red"},
            {model : "Fiat 500", color : "blue"},
            {model : "Volvo XC90", color : "black"}
        ];
});
```

I ask user to select the model from a select option and I want to print the color of selected car.

```
<p>Select a Car</p>
<select ng-model="selectedCar">
    <option ng-repeat="x in cars" value="{{x.model}}">{{x.model}}</option>
</select>
<p>Color of this car is <b style="color:{{selectedCar.color}}">{{selectedCar.color}}</b></p>
```

Here, the value for `selectedCar` is taken `x.model` instead of `x`. How to get sibling property of `model` i.e. `color` for the same variable?

Comment: I added answer, hope it will work as per the requirement. I made a very small change in the implementation. I used `ngOptions` over `ng-repeat`. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slightly change your template code and you are good to do this.

I have added Array Key as a value in the selected option and based on that key you can show the value of cars or that particular index from your array

```
<p>Select a Car</p>
<select ng-model="selectedCar">
    <option ng-repeat="(key,x) in cars" value="{{key}}">{{x.model}}</option>
</select>
<p>Color of this car is <b style="color:{{cars[selectedCar].color}}">{{cars[selectedCar].color}}</b></p>
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted exactly this kind of solution

Answer (score 0):

```js
 angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

      app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'store', function($scope, store) {
        $scope.search = '';
        $scope.cars = [];
        $scope.cars = store.getCars();
        $scope.filterProductsByCategory = function(category) {
          $scope.search = category;
        };
      }]);
      app.factory('store', function() {
          var cars = [
            {model : "Ford Mustang", color : "red"},
            {model : "Fiat 500", color : "blue"},
            {model : "Volvo XC90", color : "black"}
        ];
        return {
          getCars: function() {
            return cars;
          }
        };

      });

      angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h2>Search Car: </h2>
    <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search..." />
    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" border="1" style="width:100%;">
      <tr>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Color</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="car in cars | filter:search | orderBy:'name'">
        <td>{{car.model}}</td>
        <td>{{car.color}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I wanted this particularly for <option>. I will try to make something from your information.

Comment: Ok...If you get any question let me know so i can solve it as you want

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of **`ng-repeat`** to iterate the options.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cars = [
            {model : "Ford Mustang", color : "red"},
            {model : "Fiat 500", color : "blue"},
            {model : "Volvo XC90", color : "black"}
        ];
        
    $scope.selectedModel = function(model) {
      console.log("model");
    }    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p>Select a Car</p>
<select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="x.model for x in cars"></select>
<p>Color of this car is <b style="color:{{selectedCar.color}}">{{selectedCar.color}}</b></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I wanted this particularly for <option>.